# Weird brown substance at base of toilet

Tags: plumbing, toilet

So this has been bothering me, and I cannot find out why it's doing it.

I live in the city, and we typically don't have problems with water. None of my other appliances, sinks, tubs have the issue, but for some reason my toilet does.

My toilet is bolted to the floor, but for some reason underneath where the toilet sits, a brown residue keeps showing up. I clean it weekly when I see it, but no matter what I do, it shows up. It also has shown up as deposits in the bottom of the toilet (where the water drains at, and where the jet stream is), and is also on the outside of the toilet near the front of the bowl. It looks like hard water stains or something, but it's only the toilet that does it.

Does anybody know what could be the problem? It's like a dark brown/reddish stain that appears all around the bottom of the toilet on the floor as if water is leaking, but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

It could be fungus or algae, because the porcelain is often damp from condensation. Try a little bleach/water mix... if that quickly eliminates the stain, then it's likely biological. There can also be fungal growth in the toilet tank, but you cannot use bleach there, because it would destroy the flush (flapper) valve after some time. Try [vinegar and antiseptic cleaners](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-clean-a-toilet-tank/).

Another possibility is a leaking [wax ring gasket](https://www.lowes.com/n/how-to/replace-toilet-wax-ring). Though fairly easy to replace, I would not suggest doing it yourself *unless you own your own home*. Condominiums and apartments likely have specific requirements for plumbing. However, if you see the stain *inside* the toilet, it's not leakage from below.

If the stain is *not* fungus, it might be caused by [sulfur-reducing bacteria](https://www.uswatersystems.com/blog/iron-bacteria-and-sulfur-bacteria), which leave reddish iron (rust) deposits. You might need to treat the water, or use [Rust Out or Iron Out](https://www.homedepot.com/s/rust%2520out?NCNI-5) to remove the stains. Some communities even provide it free to residents if there is much iron or manganese in the water supply.

Comment: Thanks! It's my home that I own. I've actually remodeled the bathroom and even before remodel the old toilet did it, too. It's weird that the toilet is the only water source in the house where it happens.

Comment: Then if you've removed the toilet, check the wax ring. As far as being the only spot with the discoloration, it could also be that the *cold* tank and *cold* water in the bowl cause condensation on the *outside*. In very damp and cold climates, some people use tempering valves to admit a little hot water to prevent condensation.